# How to pass in password to pg_dump?

Tags: bash, postgresql, shell, cron

I'm trying to create a cronjob to back up my database every night before something catastrophic happens. It looks like this command should meet my needs:

```
0 3 * * * pg_dump dbname | gzip > ~/backup/db/$(date +%Y-%m-%d).psql.gz
```

Except after running that, it expects me to type in a password. I can't do that if I run it from cron. How can I pass one in automatically?

Comment: possibly helpful post i wrote on automating pg_restore ! https://medium.com/@trinity/automating-postgres-import-from-heroku-db-to-other-db-449d5946e1fb

Comment: answer using a connection string here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/29101292/1579667

Answer (score 482, accepted):

Create a `.pgpass` file in the home directory of the account that `pg_dump` will run as.

The format is:

```
hostname:port:database:username:password
```

Then, set the file's mode to `0600`. Otherwise, it will be ignored.

```
chmod 600 ~/.pgpass
```

See the Postgresql documentation [libpq-pgpass](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html) for more details.

Comment: Create ~/.pgpass with localhost:5432:mydbname:postgres:mypass
Then chmod 600 ~/.pgpass

Comment: Possibly helpful: On Ubuntu, "sudo su postgres" to switch to the "postgres" user, then create the .pgpass file and execute the dump.

Comment: I followed your answer but still unable to succesfully create my backup file. Please see my link: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257898/pg-dump-does-not-work-in-cron . Thank you.

Comment: Works on 9.6.2 :o)

Comment: Why doesn't the password prompt (-W / --password) seem to work for this?

Comment: Note about `sudo su postgres`: that Unix user does not necessarily exists. It doesn't need to. But the DB user should.

Comment: You must put .pgpass file to "~/.pgpass" directory. See the documantation: [POSGRES Documantation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNECT-PASSFILE)

`
passfile
   Specifies the name of the file used to store passwords (see Section 34.16). Defaults to ~/.pgpass, or %APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf on Microsoft Windows. (No error is reported if this file does not exist.)
`

Comment: If you can't or don't want to have the password file in `~/.pgpass`, you can provide a different location. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76261825/4850949) for details.

Answer (score 342):

Or you can set up crontab to run a script. Inside that script you can set an environment variable like this:
`export PGPASSWORD="$put_here_the_password"`

This way if you have multiple commands that would require password you can put them all in the script. If the password changes you only have to change it in one place (the script).

And I agree with Joshua, using `pg_dump -Fc` generates the most flexible export format and is already compressed. For more info see: [pg_dump documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/app-pgdump.html)

E.g.

```
# dump the database in custom-format archive
pg_dump -Fc mydb > db.dump

# restore the database
pg_restore -d newdb db.dump
```

Comment: this is not ideal. throwing it in `.pgpass` will keep everything in one place too, without adding an extra layer of indirection. plus, if all i wanted to do with export a variable, i'd do that in my `.bashrc` file, or whatever it is.

Comment: I can see why the `.pgpass` file would be a better solution. I was just giving an alternative, not sure if it deserves a downvote though :)

Comment: I didn't downvote. That was someone else; I didn't think it warranted a downvote either. Have a +1 to make up for it.

Comment: Your suggestion “And I agree with Joshua, just use pg_dump -Fc, a lot easier.” does not really add anything to your answer/alternative. Specifically, it does not explain what it would make easier; thus it only adds confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Kissaki. I don't remember the exact context, nor do I see anything from Joshua but probably I had a good reason at that moment. I've expanded a bit on why it's a better way to dump a database using `pg_dump -Fc`: easy to reload the database + format is already compressed. And now there's a reference to `pg_dump` where anyone can dig into the details.

Comment: This solutions poses an extreme security risk. The export keyword makes this variable a part of system enviroment which means any user can inspect its value. Using env command to set this only for the execution of pg_dump/pg_restore is way much better approach.

Comment: So many haters. I appreciate this answer and am adopting it for my own application.

Comment: **Setting the PGPASSWORD environment variable is not a recommended practice by the documentation** (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html) : 
_Use of this environment variable is not recommended for security reasons, as some operating systems allow non-root users to see process environment variables via ps; instead consider using the ~/.pgpass file_

Comment: In certain environments, such as AWS on an Ubuntu EC2 instance, the default `ubuntu` user can sudo without a password, therefore using an environment variable is not really less secure. In fact its probably more secure to use the the environment variable, then immediately remove it afterward, compared to leaving the .pgpass file on disk for that `ubuntu` user to access.

Comment: _use this with docker run_

Comment: This would actually be the preferred way for docker containers.

Comment: I think it's more convenient in container world

Comment: @Levure despiste the documentation, if it exists then it was made to use. In some UC like Docker containers this is the definitive solution. Occam's razor.

Comment: This is absolutely the right solution in a variety of cases. For instance -- suppose I want to fetch the creds from secrets manager and use them ONE TIME for a pg_dump command? I don't want to edit global state of the machine to do that, that would be crazy. Put it in the env for one command, then remove it.

We're not all working on shared UNIX boxes where bad actors are sshing in and poking around. In fact I suspect that's pretty rare.

Answer (score 318):

If you want to do it in one command:

```
PGPASSWORD="mypass" pg_dump mydb > mydb.dump
```

When you prepend a command with a `VAR="val"`  prefix, those variables will be set as environment variables for the context of that command execution. So it won't be set globally in your shell session. Depending on your situation, it could be an appropriate way of providing a password to the `pg_dump` command.

Comment: **Setting the PGPASSWORD environment variable is not a recommended practice** by the documentation (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html) : 
_Use of this environment variable is not recommended for security reasons, as some operating systems allow non-root users to see process environment variables via ps; instead consider using the ~/.pgpass file_

Comment: It's still a useful comment. There are lots of deployment cases where this is still helpful.

Comment: I always got the error 'Peer authentication failed for user "username"'. Solution was: PGPASSWORD="mypass" pg_dump -U username -h localhost > mydb.dump

Comment: My opinion is that it is far better to set up an environment variable (where you have control, *where* and *how* the password will be stored) as in a known, unencrypted location. This part of the postgresql doc is faulty, and this answer is a good one.

Comment: My password had an '@' in it. This worked. I couldnt figure out how to make it work with the `postgres://` syntax. Didn't try the `.pgpass` because my postgress user has no home directory.

Comment: Just needs a Windows version...

Answer (score 236):

For a one-liner, like migrating a database you can use `--dbname` followed by a connection string (including the password) as stated in the [pg_dump manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/libpq-connect.html)

In essence.

`pg_dump --dbname=postgresql://username:password@127.0.0.1:5432/mydatabase`

**Note:** Make sure that you use the option `--dbname` instead of the shorter `-d` and use a valid URI prefix, `postgresql://` or `postgres://`.

The general URI form is:

`postgresql://[user[:password]@][netloc][:port][/dbname][?param1=value1&...]`

Best practice in your case (repetitive task in cron) this shouldn't be done because of security issues. If it weren't for `.pgpass` file I would save the connection string as an environment variable.

`export MYDB=postgresql://username:password@127.0.0.1:5432/mydatabase`

then have in your crontab

`0 3 * * * pg_dump --dbname=$MYDB | gzip > ~/backup/db/$(date +%Y-%m-%d).psql.gz`

Comment: Version 9.1 of Postgre outputs an unknown option for dbname

Comment: This was tested with versions 9.4 and 9.3 on arch and RHEL respectively. can you post your connection string? anonymized of course.

Comment: Thanks, @JosueIbarra. Tested successfully on PostgreSQL 9.3, Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I just tested again on 9.5.1 on Arch Linux, it works. Make sure to use a valid connection string with the option containing an equals sign. See **--dbname** http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/app-pgdump.html Awesome username by the way.

Comment: I tried this with 9.6 windows: pg_dump --dbname=postgresql://username:password@127.0.0.1:5432/mydatabase and while it prints out everything, it does not seem to save it anywhere, or am I missing something?

Comment: @EntryLevelR you need to pipe the output to a file in order to save it. see this relevant question http://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file

Comment: Thank you, that worked great! Would you be willing to show how to restore via command line using the psql file that is created. I am getting the following output when attempting to restore. "pg_restore: [archiver] input file appears to be a text format dump. Please use psql."

Comment: Worked great, for some reason as postgres or regular user .pgpass would not authenticate, this one liner worked.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. One liner, clear.

Comment: but, password will get logged to terminal history this way

Answer (score 100):

This one liner helps me while creating dump of a single database.

```
PGPASSWORD="yourpassword" pg_dump -U postgres -h localhost mydb > mydb.pgsql
```

Comment: helped a lot...thnxxx

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. this is the only option works for me.

Answer (score 59):

```
$ PGPASSWORD="mypass" pg_dump -i -h localhost -p 5432 -U username -F c -b -v -f dumpfilename.dump databasename
```

Comment: Nice, but sadly doesn't work for me, I get "query failed: ERROR:  permission denied for relation direction_lookup"

Comment: @Doc have you tried giving the necessary permissions to the pg user?

Comment: can't see "-i" anywhere in the pg_dump doco

Answer (score 36):

You can pass a password into pg_dump directly by using the following:

```
pg_dump "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=mydb user=myuser password=mypass" > mydb_export.sql
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While your answer may work, it has serious security implications. **Arguments of a command are visible in ps(1)**, so if a process monitors ps(1) then the password is compromised.

Comment: Yes, @JonathanRosa, you are right. But Larry Spence just answered the question. So the security issue is not a problem if this is done in docker for example.

Comment: best answer (as of ubuntu)

Answer (score 25):

@Josue Alexander Ibarra answer works on centos 7 and version 9.5 
if --dbname is not passed.

```
pg_dump postgresql://username:password@127.0.0.1:5432/mydatabase
```

Comment: You're right, that's how it's supposed to look, I think what was wrong a few years back was my shell configuration. That's why it was essential for me to use `--dbname`

Answer (score 11):

Note that, in windows, the `pgpass.conf` file must be in the following folder:

```
%APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf
```

if there's no `postgresql` folder inside the `%APPDATA%` folder, create it.

the `pgpass.conf` file content is something like:

```
localhost:5432:dbname:dbusername:dbpassword
```

cheers

Answer (score 9):

As detailed in [this blog post](https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2014/03/23/how-to-non-interactively-provide-password-for-the-postgresql-interactive-terminal/) , there are two ways to non interactively provide a password to PostgreSQL utilities such as the "pg_dump" command: using the **".pgpass"** file or using the **"PGPASSWORD"** environment variable.

Answer (score 5):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but if the system user is the same as the database user, PostgreSQL won't ask for the password - it relies on the system for authentication.  This might be a matter of configuration.

Thus, when I wanted the database owner `postgres` to backup his databases every night, I could create a crontab for it: `crontab -e -u postgres`.  Of course, `postgres` would need to be allowed to execute cron jobs; thus it must be listed in `/etc/cron.allow`, or `/etc/cron.deny` must be empty.

Comment: You're sort of right here. Default Postgres configuration uses TRUST authentication for local system accounts. However most production setups get rid of this block right after installing RDBMS.

Answer (score 5):

In windows you can set the variable with the password before use pg_dump.exe, and can automate all in a bat file, for example:

```
C:\>SET PGPASSWORD=dbpass
C:\>"folder_where_is_pg_dump\pg_dump.exe" -f "dump_file" -h "db_host" -U db_usr --schema "db_schema" "db_name"
```

Answer (score 4):

Backup over ssh with password using temporary .pgpass credentials and push to S3:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd "$(dirname "$0")"

DB_HOST="*******.*********.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com"
DB_USER="*******"
SSH_HOST="my_user@host.my_domain.com"
BUCKET_PATH="bucket_name/backup"

if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "Error: 2 arguments required"
    echo "Usage:"
    echo "  my-backup-script.sh <DB-name> <password>"
    echo "  <DB-name> = The name of the DB to backup"
    echo "  <password> = The DB password, which is also used for GPG encryption of the backup file"
    echo "Example:"
    echo "  my-backup-script.sh my_db my_password"
    exit 1
fi

DATABASE=$1
PASSWORD=$2

echo "set remote PG password .."
echo "$DB_HOST:5432:$DATABASE:$DB_USER:$PASSWORD" | ssh "$SSH_HOST" "cat > ~/.pgpass; chmod 0600 ~/.pgpass"
echo "backup over SSH and gzip the backup .."
ssh "$SSH_HOST" "pg_dump -U $DB_USER -h $DB_HOST -C --column-inserts $DATABASE" | gzip > ./tmp.gz
echo "unset remote PG password .."
echo "*********" | ssh "$SSH_HOST" "cat > ~/.pgpass"
echo "encrypt the backup .."
gpg --batch --passphrase "$PASSWORD" --cipher-algo AES256 --compression-algo BZIP2 -co "$DATABASE.sql.gz.gpg" ./tmp.gz

# Backing up to AWS obviously requires having your credentials to be set locally
# EC2 instances can use instance permissions to push files to S3
DATETIME=`date "+%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"`
aws s3 cp ./"$DATABASE.sql.gz.gpg" s3://"$BUCKET_PATH"/"$DATABASE"/db/"$DATETIME".sql.gz.gpg
# s3 is cheap, so don't worry about a little temporary duplication here
# "latest" is always good to have because it makes it easier for dev-ops to use
aws s3 cp ./"$DATABASE.sql.gz.gpg" s3://"$BUCKET_PATH"/"$DATABASE"/db/latest.sql.gz.gpg

echo "local clean-up .."
rm ./tmp.gz
rm "$DATABASE.sql.gz.gpg"

echo "-----------------------"
echo "To decrypt and extract:"
echo "-----------------------"
echo "gpg -d ./$DATABASE.sql.gz.gpg | gunzip > tmp.sql"
echo
```

Just substitute the first couple of config lines with whatever you need - obviously.
For those not interested in the S3 backup part, take it out - obviously.

This script deletes the credentials in `.pgpass` afterward because in some environments, the default SSH user can sudo without a password, for example an EC2 instance with the `ubuntu` user, so using `.pgpass` with a different host account in order to secure those credential, might be pointless.

Comment: Password will get logged to terminal `history` this way, no?

Comment: @mpen Locally, yes. Remotely, no. In my case its OK to have in my local history because its a secure VM that does not allow remote access. If in your case that is not OK, just do `history -c`. When using with Jenkins, use the `Inject passwords to the build as environment variables` option so that the password is masked

Answer (score 4):

For Windows the `pgpass.conf` file should exist on path:

```
%APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf
```

On my Windows 10 absolute path it is:

```
C:\Users\Ognjen\AppData\Roaming\postgresql\pgpass.conf
```

`Note:` If there is no postgresql folder in `%APPDATA%`, create one with `pgpass.conf` file inside it.

Content of `pgpass.conf` could be:

```
*:5432:*:*:myDbPassword
```

Or more specific content could be:

```
localhost:5432:dbName:username:password
```

`Note:` Content of `pgpass.conf` must NOT end with white spaces (after password) or the error will occur.

Answer (score 1):

A secure way of passing the password is to store it in `.pgpass` file

Content of the `.pgpass` file will be in the format:

```py
db_host:db_port:db_name:db_user:db_pass

#Eg
localhost:5432:db1:admin:tiger
localhost:5432:db2:admin:tiger
```

Now, store this file in the home directory of the user with permissions `u=rw (0600) or less`

To find the home directory of the user, use
`echo $HOME`

Restrict permissions of the file
`chmod 0600 /home/ubuntu/.pgpass`

Answer (score 1):

Another option to pass the database password is using the `PGPASSFILE` environment variable or the `passfile` URI parameter.

Both expect a password file in the format

```
hostname:port:database:username:password
```

for example

```
localhost:5432:mydatabase:dbuser:userspassword
```

as described in other answers for `~/.pgpass`, but you are not confined to this specific path and and file name. This is especially useful if you need to run `pg_dump` under a user that does not have a home directory, or if you want to keep all passwords in a specific location.

The location of the password file can be provided in one of the following two ways:

### PGPASSFILE environment variable

Set the environment variable [`PGPASSFILE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html) before executing `pg_dump`.

Example:

```
PGPASSFILE=/opt/custom/backup/.pgpass
pg_dump -U dbuser -w mydatabase >/var/custom/backups/pg_dump.mydatabase.sql
```

### passfile URI parameter

If you use the URI format to provide the database, you can add the [`passfile`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNECT-PASSFILE) parameter to it.

Example:

```
pg_dump -w "postgresql://dbuser@localhost/mydatabase?passfile=/opt/custom/backup/.pgpass" >/var/custom/backups/pg_dump.mydatabase.sql
```

(Option `-w` or `--no-password` means never issue a password prompt.)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to open pg_hba.conf and sets trust in all methods. That's works for me. Therefore the security is null.

Answer (score -1):

Another (probably not secure) way to pass password is using input redirection i.e. calling

`pg_dump [params] < [path to file containing password]`

Comment: Concerning security - this file would need to be readable by the intended user(s) only; however, anyone with root rights would be able to change the security settings, and thus to read the unencrypted password. So yes, this is insecure ...

Comment: @Tobias is there any alternative? It would seem that anyone with root rights could always see the password no matter what technique other than entering the password interactively (and the question is about cron). http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/auth-methods.html#GSSAPI-AUTH mentions GSSAPI supporting single sign-on but no mention if that works non-interactively.

Comment: Anyone with root rights can also read the .pgpass which is the recommended way. Therefore, I would not consider root access a security risk.

Answer (score -4):

the easiest way in my opinion, this:
you edit you main postgres config file: pg_hba.conf
there you have to add the following line:

`host <you_db_name> <you_db_owner> 127.0.0.1/32 trust`

and after this you need start you cron thus:

`pg_dump -h 127.0.0.1 -U <you_db_user> <you_db_name> | gzip > /backup/db/$(date +%Y-%m-%d).psql.gz`

and it worked without password

Comment: And you just destroyed system security. OK for a dev box, but nothing else.