# Is there any way to fix pgpass.conf to work properly on Windows?

Tags: windows, postgresql, batch-file, pgadmin

Base on my previous question [How to fix Automated Backup script for postgres [Window]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56015566/how-to-fix-automated-backup-script-for-postgres-window/56016864?noredirect=1#comment98679782_56016864).

It looks like there is some problem with `pgpass.conf` on my PC which does not seem to provide the required password when try to backup the database using `pg_dump`. I have found that I have a weird situation. However, I could not figure out how to solve this.

1. On my PC, there is no `postgresql` folder to keep `pgpass.conf` -> I have try to install Postgres, but it looks like the error message shows

   > problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly. The database cluster initialisation failed.

   However, I already have a `pgAdmin` folder on my PC.
2. I have tried to find `pgpass.conf` by using `dir /s | find /i "pgpass.conf"` from root `c:\` .

   The result looks like it does not even exist on my PC -> So that's why I tried to create a new file for `pgpass.conf` inside the folder `pgAdmin` instead of the `postgresql` folder.
3. I have tried to set an environment variable as well, based on [What do I need for pg_dumpall to work without a password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19282928/what-do-i-need-for-pg-dumpall-to-work-without-a-password). The error on the console shows

   > 'PGPASSWORD' is not recognized as an internal or external command

   I have tried to add/edit the script like this

```
@echo off    
  echo 192.168.1.161:5432:_wolfcom:postgres:1234>"%APPDATA%\pgAdmin\pgpass.conf"
  set "root=C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v3\runtime\"
  cd /d "%root%"
  PGPASSWORD=R0m3o^%%Ech0-5910^& pg_dumpall -h 192.168.1.161 -w -U postgres _wolfcom > "D:\Backup\DatabaseBackUp\32312.sql" 
  pause
```

Can someone figure out how to let `pgpass.conf` work properly ?

Here is the current script for the batch file

```
@echo off    
  echo 192.168.1.161:5432:_wolfcom:postgres:R0m3o^%%Ech0-5910^&>"%APPDATA%\pgAdmin\pgpass.conf"
  set "root=C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v3\runtime\"
  cd /d "%root%"
  pg_dump.exe -h 192.168.1.161 -p 5432 -U postgres -F c -b -v -f "D:\Backup\DatabaseBackUp\SQL\123456.backup" _wolfcom
  pause
```

Here is Script which work for me

```
@echo off    
  echo 192.168.1.161:5432:_wolfcom:postgres:R0m3o^%%Ech0-5910^&>"%APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf"
  set "root=C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v3\runtime\"
  cd /d "%root%"
  pg_dump.exe -h 192.168.1.161 -p 5432 -U postgres -F c -b -v -f "D:\Backup\DatabaseBackUp\SQL\123456.backup" _wolfcom
  pause
```

Comment: as mentioned in my other answer's comment, it is expecting the file in postgresql, not pgAdmin. so creeate the dir, redirect to that folder.

Comment: `PGPASSWORD=R0m3o^%%Ech0-5910^` is a unixstyle "inline" definition of an environment variable. That won't work in Windows. You need to run a `SET "PGPASSWORD=..."` before calling `pg_dump`

Comment: Finally, I can back up database!!!! . Thank you so much both of you. What i have done is just create postgresql (just only new folder and new pgpass.conf ) without installing postgres.

Comment: I will added my new script in the question which work for me and hopefully will be benefit for others

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html) says:

> On Microsoft Windows the file is named `%APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf` (where `%APPDATA%` refers to the Application Data subdirectory in the user's profile).

You don't have to search for it, it has to be exactly in this place (unless you set the `PGPASSFILE` environment variable). If it doesn't exist, create it.

An alternative (and maybe simpler) way is to use pgAdmin and check the checkbox that makes it save the password for you. That creates the password file automatically.

Comment: Do you mean reset/clear password  something like this https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/dev/reset_passwords.html ?

Comment: No. The checkbox is (or used to be) in the dialog where you enter the password.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I finally solved it (see my reply on other comments).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Ok i got it

Answer (score 5):

The Postgres documentation is good, but not completely clear.

On my system (Windows 10), %APPDATA% was `C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming`; so the file had to be in `C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\postgresql\pgpass.conf` to be found by Postgres.

While I had tried placing it under `<UserName>\AppData` initially, that didn't work. Use `echo %APPDATA%` from the command-line to confirm the correct location on your system.