# How can I supply a password to a console application?

Tags: c#, redirect, console

As I come across issues when testing my current application, I often have to tweak the database the app uses.  After losing important changes several times, I wrote a program that will back up my database to a file and then check the file into SubVersion.  I have found that that backup application is not good enough.

The database is a PostgreSQL database, and my backup application invokes pg_dump to create the backup file.  pg_dump is executed in a console window.  When the database was on my own machine, it worked well.  But when I moved the database to our test server, pg_dump asked for a password.  While it's not that big a deal, I'd like to be able to supply the password automatically, since it is available in the backup application.

I've tried to follow advice I've found here, but pg_dump still stops and asks for a password.  Here's the code that I thought should have supplied the password:

```
Process backupProcess = new Process();
backupProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
backupProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
backupProcess.StartInfo.FileName = dumpPath + "pg_dump.exe";
backupProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = " --host " + host + 
                                    " --port " + port + 
                                    " --username " + userName + 
                                    " --format custom --blobs --verbose --file " +
                                    "\"" + txtBackupFile.Text + "\" " + dbName;
backupProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
backupProcess.Start();
StreamWriter standardInput = backupProcess.StandardInput;
standardInput.WriteLine("mypassword");
backupProcess.WaitForExit();// Waits here for the process to exit.
```

Thank you for your help.

RobR

Comment: Should really cconsider using Path.Combine(dumpPath, "pg_dump.exe") instead of "dumpPath + "pg_dump.exe".

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't realize that method existed.  That's a lot nicer than worrying about whether I have the slash or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's cheating a little bit (in the sense that it doesn't really help you answer the question of how to feed input to `pg_dump`), but you could refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2893979/39034) which suggests the use of a `.pgpass` file. It would certainly be possible to write to this file dynamically rather than try to interact with the  program once it prompts.

Info on `.pgpass` [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-pgpass.html).

Comment: Many thanks for that link.  I'll see about setting up a .pgpass file, or I might use the Python script that answer also suggests.  I haven't tried either one yet, but while I'm here I'll mark this as an accpeted answer.

Comment: It sounds as if automating interaction on the command line (like you might do using the "expect" tool or something similar) in .NET is a little unreliable. By the way, the above program works for me if you write a dummy "pg_dump.exe" that's a .NET program.

Answer (score 4):

I have solved this by using

```
backupProcess.EnvironmentVariables["PGPASSWORD"] = "password";
```

This way, I avoid the password will be stored on the computer

Comment: backupProcess.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["PGPASSWORD"]