# How to use pg_dump with a connection uri / url?

Tags: postgresql, connection-string

I can invoke `psql` like this:

```
psql postgres://...
```

How can I use `pg_dump` with a connection string in the format `postgres://...`?
Would be more convenient than breaking URI's into host, post, username, password.

Is there syntax for this?

Comment: If an answer solves your problem (such as the one by @Jorge Disaz) you should probably accept it.

Answer (score 220):

```
pg_dump postgres://username:password@my_postgres_server:5432/databasename
```

I just downloaded a dump using this format.
Optionally you can add `-f filename` to specify a local filename.

Answer (score 35):

This is for newer versions of `pg_dump`:

```
pg_dump -d postgres://username:password@my_postgres_server:5432/databasename > filename
```

Comment: I did not need the `-d` flag, it worked anyway.