# Automating a PG_DUMP of a PSQL database on Heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku, pg-dump

I'm trying to pg_dump certain schemas from my Heroku-hosted PSQL database into a local file.

Heroku provides me a `DATABASE_URL` in the form

```
# postgres://username:password@host:port/database
postgres://abcde:wxyz@ec2-21-82-72-112.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5762/riza3dj029012
```

Based on the above I tried dumping some schemas -

```
> pg_dump --username=abcde --host=ec2-21-82-72-112.compute-1.amazonaws.com --port=5762 --dbname=riza3dj029012 --create --schema=my_schema --password  > ~/pg_dump.dmp
> password: (enter password)
```

Is there any way to provide the password as a flag so I don't have to type it in manually? I want to automate this in a script.

I know `--no-password` exists, but not sure what use that is, because it just prevents prompting for a password and then authentication (obviously) fails.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try making a .pgpass file a la https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/libpq-pgpass.html or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893954/how-to-pass-in-password-to-pg-dump?

Comment: That did it for me, thanks. While it works, it's not ideal because I have to create a file with my production credentials on my local machine. If the script ever fails the `pgpass` file doesn't get cleared, my local machine now holds Production DB credentials - really bad security practice, especially at companies that go through strict security audits. I wish PSQL just took a password command line option instead.

Answer (score 1):

As @eabates mentioned in the comments you can create a .pgpass file for this purpose. More info can be found in the official documentation for Postgres: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/libpq-pgpass.html

Just create a file named .pgpass in the user home directory with as many lines as needed in the following format:

```
hostname:port:database:username:password
```