# Migrate tables from Postgres RDS to another RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have 2 Postgres RDS instances:

- Postgres RDS 1
- Postgres RDS 2

I have a 10 tables available in Postgres RDS 1 which I need to migrate to Postgres RDS 2.

Can I use `pg_dump` to directly transfer the tables?

```
pg_dump -t test_migration -h postgresrds2.cr8o9qw9mt1v.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -U postgres -d postgres | psql -d myschema -h postgresrds1.cr8o9qw9mt1v.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -U myadminuser
```

I am also aware of migrating table to S3, but I don't want to do that because it will consume a lot of time.

Comment: Yes, using `pg_dump | psql` should work nicely. Are your database names backwards, however?

Comment: Issue with `pg_dump | psql` is -- it asks for only 1 password and NOT 2 passwords. Because of which it breaks.

Comment: [How to pass in password to pg_dump?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2893954/174777), [Copy a table from one database to another in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3195125/174777), [Copying PostgreSQL database to another server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55645207/174777)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the complexity you might want to look into the Database Migration Service. If the migration you are performing isn't to hard it's probably easier to just use `pgdump | psql` but if you're migrating larger tables (1+ million rows) using DMS might be easier.