# Python subprocess error : Pass input to terminal using stdin

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, subprocess, stdin

I am trying to create an automatic pg dump backup script for PostgreSQL DB. The script ask for a DB password. I am trying to put the password using stdin. But, it's not working. 'popen.stdin.write("rootpasswordhere123#!\n")', this line not inserting the password into the script terminal.

```
import gzip
import subprocess

with gzip.open('backup.gz', 'wb') as f:
    popen = subprocess.Popen(['pg_dump', '--no-owner', '--no-acl', '-U', 'postgres', '-d', 'database_name', '-h', '178.111.11.111'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    time.sleep(5)
    popen.stdin.write("rootVidhyaDhan123#!\n") # code not working
    for stdout_line in iter(popen.stdout.readline, ""):
        f.write(stdout_line.encode('utf-8'))
    popen.stdin.close()
    popen.stdout.close()
    popen.wait()
```

Comment: You probably need to use Pexpect here: https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/. Popen is just dumping the password into stdin right away without waiting for the prompt to appear.

Comment: @shadowtalker Ok...that's why I put a sleep(10 in there).

Comment: Maybe pg_dump is trying to read the password from `/dev/tty` rather than stdn. You may want to specify a command-line flag to pg_dump to change this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Probably pg_dump is trying to read the password from `/dev/tty` rather than stdin.

Instead of using stdin, set the `PGPASSWORD` environment variable (`os.environ['PGPASSWORD'] = '...'`) or create a `.pgpass` file. Details here: [How to pass in password to pg_dump?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893954/how-to-pass-in-password-to-pg-dump)

Comment: @JintoAntony: Not with pg_dump, but with other Unix command-line tools.

Comment: Even better, use the `env=` parameter of Popen, as demonstrated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4453495/2954547