# How to automate using a production postgres database backup in local Flask environment

Tags: postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, remote-desktop

We use Postgres and Flask for our website, and we use the production database dump locally pretty often. To get a fresh dump, I use a remote desktop connection (RDC) to connect to pgAdmin then use RDC again to copy `.bak` file from server and save it locally. Likewise, I use a local instance of pdAdmin to restore the database state from the backup.

My manager asked me to automate this process to use production database each time when a local Flask instance is launched. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a shell script that dumps the database to a local file using `pg_dump`, then use `pg_restore` to build a new local database from that dump.  You could probably even just pass the output from `pg_dump` to `pg_restore`... something like

```
pg_dump --host <remote-database-host> --dbname <remote-database-name> --username <remote-username> > pg_restore --host <local-database-host> --username <local-username>
```

To get your password into `pg_dump` / `pg_restore` you'll probably want to use a .pgpass file, as described here: [How to pass in password to pg_dump?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893954/how-to-pass-in-password-to-pg-dump)

If you want this to happen automatically when you launch a Flask instance locally, you could call the shell script from your initialization code using a `subprocess` call if a LOCAL_INSTANCE environment variable is set, or something along those lines

Comment: thanks, but I have some other question about this. I tried to import pg_dump from sh, but as I know sh is not support for window. So do you have any document about subprocess