# How to pass password StandardInput to pg_dump?

Tags: c#, postgresql, pg-dump

I'm creating Process to run pg_dump.exe in C#

```cs
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    Arguments = @"-U postgres -W -f D:\postgres\test123_dump.sql postgres",
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    FileName = @"C:\PostgreSQL\bin\pg_dump.exe",
    UseShellExecute = false,
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
    RedirectStandardInput = true
};

Process process = new Process() { StartInfo = processStartInfo, EnableRaisingEvents = true };

process.Start();

using( StreamWriter sw = process.StandardInput)
{
    sw.WriteLine("123"); // test password
};
```

It will run pg_dump.exe, it will show prompt to pass the password, but StreamWriter seems to not work for some reason.

Comment: Try adding flush : sw.Flush();

Comment: @jdweng i tried

Comment: Do you wait for prompt before writing password?

Comment: @jdweng nah, but in StandardOutput or StandardError this prompt are not showed

Comment: You can't use ReadLine(), you must use Read().  And you have to loop because it may not be there immediately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this string to put your authentication info directly in argument list

```
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        Arguments = @"--dbname=postgresql://user_name:pass_word@Localhost:5432/bd_name_to_save -F c -b -f output_bd_name",
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        FileName = @"C:\PostgreSQL\bin\pg_dump.exe",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
        RedirectStandardInput = true
    };
    
    Process process = new Process() { StartInfo = processStartInfo, EnableRaisingEvents = true };
    
    process.Start();
```

Comment: That's working, but is there any other method like my StreamWriter to pass password?

Comment: checks here , there are another way by saving the password : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893954/how-to-pass-in-password-to-pg-dump