# Zero bytes when backup using pg_dump and pg_dumpall using CRONTAB

Tags: linux, postgresql, cron, pg-dump

I want to backup using crontab with pg_dump. But the file generated is always 0 kb. These are the commands I have used :

```
* * * * * /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/pg_dump -h 127.0.0.1 -Fc db_kp -f /backup-nfs/dump_dbkp_TEST1`date +\%d-\%m-\%y`.sql  
* * * * * /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/pg_dump -h 127.0.0.1 -Fc db_kp > /backup-nfs/dump_dbkp_TEST2`date +\%d-\%m-\%y`.sql 
* * * * * /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/pg_dump -h 10.100.8.43 -Fc db_kp > /backup-nfs/DMP_dbkp_TEST3`date +\%d-\%m-\%y`.sql 
* * * * * /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/pg_dump -h 10.100.8.43 -Fc db_kp -f /backup-nfs/DMP_dbkp_TEST4`date +\%d-\%m-\%y`.sql  
* * * * * pg_dump -h 10.100.8.43 -Fc db_kp -f /backup-nfs/DMP_dbkp_TEST5`date +\%d-\%m-\%y`.bak
* * * * * pg_dump -h 10.100.8.43 -Fc db_kp > /backup-nfs/DMP_dbkp_TEST6`date +\%d-\%m-\%y`.bak
```

All fail !

I can do just fine without crontab : `pg_dump -h 127.0.0.1 -Fc db_kp -f /backup-nfs/dump_dbkp_TEST`date +%d-%m-%y`.sql`

And this happens with pg_dumpall too.

`pg_dump` and `pg_dumpall` are on this directory, I have made sure : **/usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/**

What is actually going on?

Help please.

thanks

**UPDATE**

Finally I solved it. Essentially add this `pg_dump --dbname=postgresql://username:password@127.0.0.1:5432/mydatabase` I read it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893954/how-to-pass-in-password-to-pg-dump).

Here is my final crontab command :

```
* * * * * /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/pg_dump -h 10.100.8.43 -Fc --dbname=postgresql://[your user]:[password]@10.100.8.43:5432/db_kpx -f /backup-nfs/DMP_TEST`date +\%d-\%m-\%y`.sql
```

Of course you have to adjust * * * * * according to your need.

Comment: A difference between run by command and run by crontab is the user who does the action. 
Probably the crontab doesn't have permission to access your database.

Comment: I think so. How do I add the permission ? @rodrigo

Comment: I would use `-U <some_user>` to specify the Postgres database user you wish to connect as. Preferably a user that has the necessary permissions in the database to dump all the objects and data.

Comment: Wouldn't it require password when run ? @Adrian Klaver

Comment: 1) Depends on how your `pg_hba.conf` is configured. 2) If it requires a password then either [.pgpass](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html), [service file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgservice.html) or [PGPASSWORD](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html) environment variable could be used.

Answer (score 1):

The zero-byte file indicates that `>` redirection is
working properly, and that the crontab user has write permission
in that directory.
Verify that the owner of the zero-byte file is identical
to your interactive UID when you tested `pg_dump` and saw success.

The output is zero bytes because nothing appeared on stdout.
But I bet some diagnostic was output to stderr.
If your crontab had a MAILTO pointed at your inbox,
you would have seen that diagnostic.
Consult `$ man 5 crontab` and note the part that starts

> If MAILTO is defined ...

Test sending mail interactively from the command line,
to verify mail is correctly configured on your cron server.

---

In addition to logging stdout with `cmd > out.log`,
you might want to capture stderr:

```bash
cmd  > out.log  2> err.log
```

Comment: I run pg_dump using user `postgres`. And I have confirmed the 0 kb files are owned by **postgres** by using command `ls -l [filename]`. In fact, all files (the zero and non-zero size) on dir `/backup-nfs` are owned by postgres   @J_H