# How to enter the requested data in the terminal

Tags: python

I had a problem entering the password directly through the python program

When I do something in PostgreSQL, it asks for a database password and here

How can I enter the database password through python so that it is entered in the requested field

```
pg_dump.exe -U dbuser -h localhost dbname >> s.sql
>>>Password:
```

I know that there is a .pgpass file, but there is a possibility of frequent password changes

Comment: have you tried `echo password | pg_dump.exe -U dbuser -h localhost dbname >> s.sql` ?

Comment: @azro it still asks for password

Comment: Did you look at [How to pass in password to pg_dump?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893954/how-to-pass-in-password-to-pg-dump) ?

Comment: I don't understand yet what this has to do with Python.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I entered the postgresql command as an example to make it clear where I want to enter the value using python