# pg_dump : error: connexion to database « dbdev » failed : fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I am trying to use pg_dump command in a container without entering the password.

I firstly checked pg_dump with password entered in promp, when I do

```
pg_dump -Fp --host my_hostname --port 32045 --dbname dbdev --username pgsqladmin test.sql
```

it ask me the password. I enter it and it works.

When I try:

```
pg_dump -Fp --host my_hostnae --port 32045 --dbname dbdev --username pgsqladmin -w test.sql
```

I have the error:

> pg_dump: error: connexion to database « dbdev » failed : fe_sendauth: no password supplied

I am working with PGAAS. What modifications can I do in order to avoid this error?

I use .pgpass file and I set ENV PGPASSFILE=/opt/nifi/.pgpass

.pgpass file has chmod 0600
And it looks like : `hostname:port:database:username:password`

Comment: I don't know what '/opt/nifi' is, seems like a weird name for your home directory.  But '.pgpass' has two 's' in it, not one.

Comment: Either the contents of the password file are wrong, or the permissions on that file. But you didn't tell us how either is configured.

Comment: It's a mistake in my post, it is well .pgass name. I work with a container having Apache Nifi ETL and postgresql client in the same container. I built a dockerfile where workdir is opt/nifi/nifi-current/

Answer (score 0):

I believe this was answered here?

[How to pass in password to pg_dump?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893954/how-to-pass-in-password-to-pg-dump)

Make sure your file is .pgpass and not .pgpas and that it is chmod to 600

Comment: The name is well .pgpass, and I gave chmod 0600 to this file

Comment: If you look in the link in the answer you could check to see if PGPASSWORD works for you. If that is the case, then it could easily be a typo or malformed character in your .pgpass file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, @TroyMeyerink I am able to do PGPASSWORD="mypass" pg_dump -U pgsqladmin -h hostname -d database -p 32045 -f test.sql and with ls in terminal I see the dump. But when I do : pg_dump -U pgsqladmin -h hostname -d database -p 32045 -w -f test.sql I have the error no password supplied